# Division of big numbers in a smart contract

Tags: solidity, math

I am building a function that will payout dividends based on the percentage of tokens owned.

```
    function simulateRent() public payable{
        uint256 rent_received = msg.value;
       
        for (uint i = 0; i < ownersCount; i++) {
            uint256 calculateRent = balanceOf(address(owners[i]))*(rent_received)/_totalSupply;
            payable(address(owners[i])).transfer(calculateRent);
        }
    }
```

This function seems to work when I have simple numbers, e.g. if total supply is 1M and each person owns half, then the `msg.amount` will be split in half and divided equally. However, I encounter problems when dealing with more than 2 owners and especially when their number of tokens owned isn't easily divisible.

I was wondering how can I make this calculation?

For context:
Total supply is 1M*e18 (18 decimals). Incoming payable amount will be around 1 ETH (it can be less than 1 ETH).

Comment: Use [PRBMath](https://github.com/paulrberg/prb-math).

Answer (score 0):

A way to solve this problem:

```
         isFactor?
         /       \
       yes        no
       /           \
calculateRent   introduce 'x' so that
                input - x = factor
                      \
                calculateRent
```

> A factor is a number that divides the given number without any remainder.

- Verify that `balanceOf(address(owners[i]))*(rent_received)` is divisible by `_totalSupply`, if they are not, make them divisible.
- This will be achieved by **calculating the modulus** of the mentioned inputs. If the output is 0, then you are good to go, otherwise, one of the inputs will have to be changed.
- Knowing that the factors of `_totalSupply` is dependent on
  `balanceOf(address(owners[i]))` and `rent_received`, you might
  consider adding a new variable `x` to the formula, the factor will
  look something like this:

```
factor = balanceOf(address(owners[i])) * (rent_received - x) 
                                                       /* ^
                                                          |___ will be substracted from the amount
                                                               received so it will be equal to the 
                                                               closest factor*/
```

Comment: SafeMath is no longer necessary in Solidity v0.8 and above. [Is the SafeMath library obsolete in solidity 0.8.0?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/91367/is-the-safemath-library-obsolete-in-solidity-0-8-0/112517#112517).

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I wasn't aware of that