# What's the execution order in SafeMath?

Tags: solidity

When using OpenZeppelin's `SafeMath` library, what's the execution order when we do something like this?

```
v = v1.add(v2).mul(v3)
```

Is it `(v1 + v2) * v3` or `v1 + v2 * v3`?

Comment: What version of Solidity are you using? In v0.8, [you don't need to use SafeMath anymore](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/91367/is-the-safemath-library-obsolete-in-solidity-0-8-0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's left to right.

`v1.add(v2) => .mul(v3)`

Hope it helps.