# Fail with error 'SafeMath: subtraction overflow'

Tags: kovan, test, create

I am trying to use the "create" function from an LSP smart contract from the UMA protocol but I can not use it it always returns the "Fail with error 'SafeMath: subtraction overflow'" error. I am using the Kovan testnet and the smart contract address is: 0xDfF8F001824D6128f6BA16eAB0Fd8d1cc43Ef053

To call this contract there needs to be USDC collateral in my account which I do have (I have around 1500USDC) and KovanEth which I also do have. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

The link to the smart contract launcher: https://github.com/UMAprotocol/launch-lsp

Comment: What version of Solidity are you using? In v0.8, [you don't need to use SafeMath anymore](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/91367/is-the-safemath-library-obsolete-in-solidity-0-8-0).

Comment: Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js) // I guess I can try to update truffle version to compile. I think this LSP smart contract is an old project (Aug21)